# How to fetch particular key value from text file into excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, macros

I need to fetch string from text file into excel sheet.
I am able to fetch only first occurrence of the string ans paste in excel(A1).
Now i need to continue fetching till EOF and paste that string in A2,A3,A4....

**Example:**

A Text file contains a xxx=100 key value multiple times in text file.
xxx is constant while value is changes every time . 
so i need to fetch all xxx value from text file and 
paste it in each individual excel cell.

**My code:**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer

myFile = "C:\test\test.log"

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)

Line Input #1, textline

text = text & textline

Loop

Close #1

posLat = InStr(text, "Response Code")

Range("A1").Value = Mid(text, posLat + 15, 3)

End Sub
```

Comment: show the code you have so far. It will be easy to provide missing guidelines seeing your code

Comment: @KazimierzJawor sir i  have updated my post with code

Answer (score 1):

Try with this improved code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim myFile As String, text As String, textline As String, posLat As Integer, posLong As Integer
Dim I as long

myFile = "C:\test\test.log"

Open myFile For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)

Line Input #1, textline

'text = text & textline
text = textLine

posLat = InStr(text, "Response Code")

Range("A1").Offset(I,0).Value = Mid(text, posLat + 15, 3)
 I= I+1

Loop

Close #1


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know what you have inside you text file and why you suggested to use `text = text & textline` which could be redundant. Try with `text = textLine` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim valsArray As Variant
    Dim text  As String, vals As String
    Dim iVal As Long

    myFile = "C:\test\test.log"

    Open myFile For Input As #1
    text = Input$(LOF(1), #1) '<--| read all file in a string
    Close #1

    valsArray = Split(text, "Response Code=") '<--| split text file into bits separated by "Response Code=" string
    For iVal = 1 To UBound(valsArray) '<--| loop through generated array skipping its first element
        vals = vals & Left(valsArray(iVal), 3) & "," '<--| build values string delimited by a comma
    Next iVal
    valsArray = Split(Left(vals, Len(vals) - 1), ",") '<--| split values string into an array
    Range("A1").Resize(UBound(valsArray) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(valsArray) '<--| write down the array
End Sub
```

Comment: @virajshirsat, did you get through it?